# german words in ubuntu /usr/share/dict

Tags: language-support, dictionary

I found some stuff in ubuntu package installer: old-german, and german-medical library. But these are not what I am looking for. I need a words list (with more than 100K words) of standard german language. (no word definition is required, just one word per line txt file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Ubuntu Software Center there are four packages for German: *aspell-de*, *hunspell-de-de* (core version), *hunspell-de-de-frami* (enhanced version) and *myspell-de-de* . These are the "standard" packages which have Germany as the locale. The *hunspell-de-de-frami* package (~230,000 words) contains a enhanced version with some words missing in the base dictionary or not (yet) belonging to the "core" German words (~74,000 words). *myspell-de-de* is particularly useful because the myspell spellchecker is currently used within the Mozilla spellchecker, so it can be used for spellchecking in Firefox.